# How do I make an Excel ActiveX label to be transparent ... at runtime?

Tags: excel, vba, label, runtime, transparent

I want to put a transparent label on top of a sheet in Excel, so that I can take advantage of the MouseMove event of the label to "draw cells" (aka change their fill color and so on) by mouse click / drag / etc. - since I can't do that on the cells per se.

Now everything works just fine, except that I can't make the label transparent at runtime (aka in VBA) ... while by doing exactly the same thing in Design Mode works as expected. Specifically, I have the code (more or less):

```
Dim MapLabel As OLEObject
On Error Resume Next
Sheet2.OLEObjects("MapLabel").Delete
Set MapLabel = Sheet2.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Label.1")
MapLabel.name = "MapLabel"
MapLabel.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
MapLabel.Object.Caption = ""
' Problem line below
MapLabel.Object.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
' Problem line above
MapLabel.Left = Sheet2.cells(2, 6).Left
MapLabel.Top = Sheet2.cells(2, 6).Top
MapLabel.Width = Sheet2.cells(2,6).Width * 10
MapLabel.Height = Sheet2.cells(2,6).Height * 10
```

So, in words, I first delete the label named 'MapLabel', then recreate it (the above code goes into a "init" Sub). All the code lines except the one marked produce the desired result. The marked one **does** set the BackStyle property of the label to fmBackStyleTransparent ... but it **doesn't** actually make the label transparent. This is frustrating, because it's the same approach that works flawlessly at design time!

Do you have a solution to this? I read about solving similar problems by declaring the label as MsForms.Label or as Control, but the sheet object doesn't have those properties, plus, there are far more label properties which can be set using the OLEObject than with the help of MsForms.Label or Control.

Comment: why are you deleting it and recreating it? as a test it works fine for me with an activex label, at run time it changes from transparent to opaque using `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Label1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque Then

 Label1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
 
Else

Label1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End If

 
 
End Sub
`

Comment: @StevenMartin I'm deleting it in case any of its properties has been changed by the user last time when working with the workbook. Those properties are essential for what I want to achieve (e.g. transparency, position, etc). Recreating it, so that I can use it again, obviously. Regarding your test, you won't be able to access the SelectionChange event of the cells, because the label will cover the said cells (so that I can use MouseMove, MouseDown event _on the space_ of those cells (not the cells per se)... if you know what I mean.

Comment: @StevenMartin Oh, and one more thing: as I said in my post, the Backstyle property of the label **already is** fmBackStyleTransparent. It's just that the label is not transparent, as the property indicates it should be.

Comment: Just tried the same code (with and without the delete part, to check if Steven had a point with what he said) in a completely blank workbook's Workbook_Open event _and_ its sheet's Worksheet_SelectionChange event. Same result.

Comment: But this works fine for me , I have set the active x label to background Color of red and then clicking a cell alternates between red and transparent,  possibly u could try adding 'Do Events' after ur transparent command

Comment: Btw are you 100% sure you are adding an active x label to the blank workbook or a forms label?

Comment: Steve, that's EXACTLY the same code as above, just put into the Workbook_Open event of a blank workbook. Copied your code to the Worksheet_SelectionChange event. Added DoEvents. Same thing. Regarding your last question, well, the label being added is the label dynamically designed in the code above - nothing more, nothing less. And yes, I strongly believe it's an ActiveX label - the "normal" ones (aka Form ones) look entirely different (like a frame, already transparent in the middle). I'm using Excel 2007, by the way.

Comment: One other thing, Steve: if you do things manually (aka in Design mode), everything works flawlessly. If I do it programatically, in the code (aka VBA), now that's when transparency doesn't really work. So if you want to see it "not working", do everything in code (e.g. set transparency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do after this line:

> MapLabel.Object.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent

put this line:

> ActiveSheet.Shapes(MapLabel.Name).Fill.Transparency = 1

I hope I helped.

P.S. If you need explanation i will edit my answer.

Comment: I tested this on the simplified example in my question and it worked, but only when not clicking on the label's surface. However, in my actual code, I had this issue already solved right from the start, with a Private Sub MapLabel_Click()
    Sheet2.MapLabel.Visible = False
    Sheet2.MapLabel.Visible = True
End Sub, so I'll mark this as an answer, since it does exactly what I wanted. The only inconvenient is that the answer came a little late, but then, better later than never. Thank you.

Comment: First off all you welcome. Yes, you are right, when you click the object you lose the transparency. And your solution is the best way to refresh the object.

Comment: `MapLabel.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 1` or `MapLabel.ShapeRange(1).Fill.Transparency = 1`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you but in Word. The solution for me was to do the following:

In design mode:

1. Right click on the object
2. Navigate to `Switch to automatic form/Image` > `Wrapping` > `In front of the text`
3. Add an empty picture to your label

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution - maybe it helps others. Unfortunately, in my case the problem occured in Excel, and when trying to do it programatically, in code. As I said above, when doing things in design mode - even in Excel - it works flawlessly. Not in code though...

Comment: Yea, I tried to do this, sorry.. it doesn't work in Excel. The properties for the textbox OLEObject doesn't have the option to set a background image :c (I made a transparent png in GIMP, but there's no where to load it to the form)